# How to count the number of line boxes in a DIV or P

Tags: javascript, dom, caret

```
<div><span>aaaaaa</span> ... (many other span here) ... <span>zzzzzz</span></div>
```

In that case, the boxes span are placed on few line-boxes inside the div.
(The span elements can use different font-size.)

1) How can we know the number of the line-boxes ?

2) Can we know on which line-boxe an element span is placed ?

3) Can we know on which line-boxe the caret is placed (contenteditable) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll suppose the DOM in your example is an effective example of the actual complexity of your DOM, and that a "line-boxe" is just a line of text.

1-2) For every `<span>` inside the `<div>`, you can count the number of lines they span with something like this:

```
var spans = div.getElementsByTagName("span"), spandata = [];
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    var rects = spans[i].getClientRects();
    if (i > 0)
        if (rects[0].bottom > obj.rects[obj.rects - 1].bottom)
            var inirow = obj.lastRow + 1;
        else var inirow = obj.lastRow;
    var obj = {
        element: spans[i],
        rects: rects,
        iniRow: inirow,
        lastRow: inirow + rects.length - 1
    };
    spandata.push(obj);
}
```

Now `spandata` is a list of all the data you want about the `<span>` elements. I'm also supposing that each one of them may span through more than one line.

Keep in mind that `getClientRects` has some issues in IE<8.

3) In modern browsers, the `getSelection` method can help you:

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
if (sel.type === "Caret")
    var span = sel.anchorNode.parentNode;
```

About the line position, I must say it's not an easy task. You can't easily get the page position of the caret. The simplest thing you can do is to place a dummy inline element in the place of the caret:

```
var text = sel.anchorNode.nodeValue;
sel.anchorNode.nodeValue = text.substring(0, sel.anchorOffset);
var dummy = document.createElement("i");
span.appendChild(dummy);
var pos = dummy.getBoundingClientRect();
sel.anchorNode.nodeValue = text;
span.removeChild(dummy);
```

`pos` contains the info of the position of the caret. Now you have to compare them with the rect infos about the span:

```
var rects = span.getClientRects();
for (var i = 0; i < rects.length; i++)
    if (rects[i]].bottom === pos.bottom) break;

if (i < rects.length) {
   for (var i = 0; i < spandata.length; i++) {
       if (spandata[i].element === span) {
           var line = spandata[i].iniRow + i;
           break;
       }
   }
}
```

In the end, if `line != null`, it contains the line of the caret.

Man, that was complicated...

Comment: No, if you want to keep things simple and eventually not responding to the answer...

Comment: @MaxArt Thank you a lot for your answer. I will study it right now.

Comment: @Christophe - If this answer has helped you, please up-vote it and mark it as your accepted answer.

Comment: I think he can't up-vote yet, but he can accept the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your `div` is in the `el` variable:

```
el.children.length; // Number of direct children

// You have one of the children in the "child" variable, to know its index:
[].indexOf.call( el.children, child ); // Index of child in el.children
```

I'm not mentioning the cross-browser issues there, but `Array.prototype.indexOf` is only available starting IE9 (so it works in all modern browsers).